# L'Hopital's Rule on Limits with Trigonometric Functions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How do trigonometric functions affect the solving of limit as x grows arbitrarily large? Aren't trigonometric functions cyclical - meaning they wouldn't have any answer for $\lim_{x\to\infty}$?
How is the problem $\lim_{x\to \infty} (1-{\cos{(3x)}})^x$ solved?

Comment: Why would you use L'Hospital's rule for this one?

Comment: How would you solve it?

Comment: I never use L'Hospital, as there are conditions to apply it that no one ever checks. I mostly use Taylor's expansion at the relevant order , or equivalent functions (asymptotic analysis). Thzt being said, this function has no limit at infinity.

Comment: I took the problem from my textbook which had the answer listed as 1. Is that a mistake on their part?

Comment: Probably (if you haven't forgotten some specific hypotheses on $x$ as $\cos 3x $  have the same value periodically, and this value can be $1$, or $-1$ or $1$, so you have subsequences which tend to $0$, or are always equal to $1$ or are in turns $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could write this particular function as $$\exp[x\log(1-\cos(3x))],$$ and the problem simply reduces to taking the limit of $x\log(1-\cos(3x))$ since $\exp{}$ is continuous.

But as $x$ goes to $+\infty,$ the argument of the $\log{}$ only hurtles continuously between $1$ and $2$ because of the cosine, so that the logarithm bounces continuously between $0$ and $\log 2.$ The other factor, $x,$ in the meantime grows without bound.

So combining these two behaviours, you see that you have a function which gets arbitrarily large in magnitude but fluctuates continuously between positive and negative values. So the limit does not exist.

There is no need to use L'hopital here. One uses it in cases where one has a limiting value of the form $0/0,$ and cases that can be reduced to this. No such thing happens here. There simply isn't any limiting value.

Answer (score 0):

This limit does not exist.

Take $x_n=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n$ and $x_n=\frac{\pi}{12}+2\pi n$, where $n\rightarrow+\infty$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also, I took the problem from my book which gives the answer as 1 but I can't figure out how they got it.

Comment: @Hoppy For the first sequence $1-\cos3x_n=1$ and the expression is closed to $1$, but for the second sequence this expression is closed to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @Hoppy What exactly? Ask please a concrete question.

Comment: By the second sequence do you mean raising the function to the x power? And, if that makes the expression approach zero, then why do I have it listed as 1?

Comment: @Hoppy Because $\cos\left(3\cdot\frac{\pi}{12}\right)=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $0<1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}<1.$